# deploying c++/qml application - packing qml files into bin

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a c++/qml applicaiton. My/custom qml files are packed in a resource file and loading well. My problem is that when I deploy my application I need to have in bin directory also all the QtQuick/QtQuick2 directories with all their content. Is there a way to have them packed/included in compiled .exe file? In theory I could include all in a resource file, but that seems like overkill.

Is there some way how to handle this?

Comment: Did you see this? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: Check this: http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static linking to make a standalone executable:

https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows